# Alternative for pcshow() function in matlab

Tags: image-processing, matlab-cvst

I'm using Matlab R2015a and I want [estimate depth](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/depth-estimation-from-stereo-video.html?s_tid=srchtitle)
but an error occurs and I wonder that it doesn't know pcshow() function. Why it doesn't work and is there another alternative for that?[image]

Comment: It seems that you simply do not have installed the toolbox that pcshow is part of. Are you able to get additional toolboxes ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is entirely on the use MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

pcshow() was implemented in 2015b and in R2015a the equivalent function is called showPointCloud.